# The debugger menu "set next statement " can't work in VS2012 Unit test project?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I am face the weird issue, the debugger menu "set next statement " can't work in VS2012 Unit test project? it always pop up the alert dialog says "Unable to set the next statement to this location". But I can use this menu in other kind project,e.g asp.net, winform, wpf etc.
Has anyone got the same issue?

Comment: There can be an issue with the statement you are trying to set the next statement to. Did you try another line in source code? It you are debugging the tests, there should be no difference with ordinary code.

Comment: I don't think so, any statement can't be set in next statement in unit test.even there is just a simple statement like x=0; Can you use that menu in Unit test?

Comment: I haven't used unit tests in VS2012, but in VS2010 all the debugging facilities work fine.

Answer (score 3):

I know what's going on. It seems the defect of use the fakes framework in Unit test. If I remove the fakes assembly in Unit test, the set next statement is work fine. If I add any fakes assembly it doesn't work.